# AngularFire2 Firestore: Only getting 50 results

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have two functions:

```
async test1() {
  const items = await this.afs.collection(`items`).valueChanges().pipe(take(1)).toPromise());
  console.log(items.length);
}

async test2() {
  const items = await this.afs.collection(`accounts/trgdfedrtrtr4J/items`).valueChanges().pipe(take(1)).toPromise());
  console.log(items.length);
}
```

The first gives me 50 results, and the second gives me 880 results, but they BOTH have 880 items!

Does anyone know what could cause this? I have no other code so Firestore just isn't sending all the items when I get them. I also tried `ref.limit(1000)` but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

db = firebase.firestore();

const items = await this.db.collection(`items`).get();
```

retrieves all results. Not sure what the problem was...